# create DB backup postgresql using java

Tags: java, postgresql

I try to backup my database in posgresql using Java, but when I run my program, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pg_dump": CreateProcess error=2, specified file not found

This is my code

```
      String path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PostgreSQL\\9.1\\bin\\pg_dump.exe";
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

//PostgreSQL variables    
String host = "localhost";
String user = "postgres";
String dbase = "GestionPharmacie";
String password = "*****";
Process p;
ProcessBuilder pb;


r = Runtime.getRuntime();        
pb = new ProcessBuilder("pg_dump", "-v", "-h", host, "-f", path, "-U", user, dbase);
pb.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", password);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
p = pb.start();
```

Comment: did you try this `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE  filename  FROM tablename`.

Comment: @Satya: there is no `select .. into outfile...` in Postgres.

Comment: "*specified file not found*" is pretty obvious: you need to supply the full path to the executable, e.g `"c:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\bin\\pg_dump"`

Comment: i modify my code but i have same error

Comment: `ProcessBuilder("pg_dump"...` is **not** using the full path

Answer (score 1):

-D is a invalid option, and I put a host attribute.

```
{
    String path = "D:\\aaa";
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

    //PostgreSQL variables    
    String host = "localhost";
    String user = "postgres";
    String dbase = "GestionPharmacie";
    String password = "*****";
    Process p;
    ProcessBuilder pb;


    r = Runtime.getRuntime();        
    pb = new ProcessBuilder("pg_dump", "-v", "-h", host, "-f", path, "-U", user, dbase);
    pb.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", password);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    p = pb.start();        

} catch (Exception e) {
```

Comment: i have nothing, i dont found backup file in path

Comment: i get this error Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pg_dump": CreateProcess error=2, specified file not found

Comment: Sure, what is your path enviroment to execute pg_dump?, you're using windows system?, if true, put the full path to pg_dump installation ("C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\VERSION\\bin\\pg_dump.exe")

Comment: i modify but i have same error

Comment: I'am sure the problem is the path installation, please check this